# Is it necessary $A^TA =I$ if $AA^T=I$ where A is a square matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose if $AA^T=I$ where $A$ is a square matrix, is it necessary that $A^TA=I$?

I tried to google it but didn't find anything confirmatory.

In the same way if $AA^{-1}=I$, is it necessary that $A^{-1}A=I$?

My attempt it as follows:-

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a&d&g\\
b&e&h\\
c&f&i
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+b^2+c^2&ad+be+cf&ag+bh+ci\\
da+eb+fc&d^2+e^2+f^2&dg+eh+fi\\
ga+hb+ic&gd+he+if&g^2+h^2+i^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$
$$d^2+e^2+f^2=1$$
$$g^2+h^2+i^2=1$$
$$ad+be+cf=0$$
$$ag+bh+ci=0$$
$$da+eb+fc=0$$
$$dg+eh+fi=0$$
$$ga+hb+ic=0$$
$$gd+he+if=0$$

Now if we calculate $A^TA$, it would be

$$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+d^2+g^2&ab+de+gh&agc+df+gi\\
ba+ed+hg&b^2+e^2+h^2&bc+ef+hi\\
ca+fd+ig&cb+ef+ih&c^2+f^2+i^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now can one say $a^2+d^2+g^2=1$ from the previous equations? I think not necessary. So by this exercise I doubt $A^TA=I$

I am not getting any idea for $AA^{-1}=I$

Comment: I googled "if AB = I"

Comment: yes I saw that, but nobody said clearly that it is true or not? I just want the confirmation.

Comment: There are more than 20 proofs of this facts in the link already. What sort of confirmation are you asking for besides the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because inverses are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To see this note that since $I=A^TA$ we have $A=A(A^TA)=(AA^T)A$ so $AA^T=I$.

Answer (score -3):

In addition to all this $I=I^T=(AA^T)^T =A^T(A^T)^T=A^TA $.